# Sed: Using a,c or i in a one-liner

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I use a and i in sed scripts often, but how to use them generally in a one-liner (or more specifically to signify end-of-the-text)?

I have tried quoting the text, adding a new line char to signify the end of the text, escaping the new line; nothing works, sed simply treats all chars to the end of the shell's line as being text to work with.

This causes a problem when you have other actions following, as they get treated as text and not commands for sed to execute, such as p.

This is fine:

```
/RANGE_start/,/RANGE_end/{
  s/foo/bar/
  /RANGE_end/a \--- This is the end of the range block ---
  p
}
```

This does not work fine:

```
/RANGE_start/,/RANGE_end/{s/foo/bar/;/RANGE_end/a \--- This is the end of the range block ---; p}
```

where the output is

> --- This is the end of the range block ---; p}

or, since I'm trying to use p, no output (assuming sed was started with -n).

Is there a special char I can pass to a, c and i to signify end-of-text?

(BTW, this isn't just about one-liners, (in a different question I ask) it's also about writing to a file using w where the text does not get written to the file.)

[I suspect I'm using some Gnu specifics above.]

Comment: does your standard `sed` produce output for `sed --version` ? Please add that to your Q. If not, AND as you have tagged your Q with `unix`, your sed may be an old version that requires `\a\,i\,c\.` to be the last chars on the line, followed by the add, ins, or change text on separate lines until a blank line terminates the "input" to that operation. One liners are, IMHO, highly overrated. Wait until you have to improve someone else's oneliner when you take over some code, you won't like them so much, but yes, sometimes because of other tools limitations you need the one-liner ;-). Good luck!

Comment: One-liner is a pejorative term — it is not an objective to be achieved at all costs.  In my book, if you're using the `a`, `c`, `i` commands in `sed`, you are foregoing the 'one-liner' options.  If you feel you must and are using GNU `sed`, you can put each 'line' into a separate `-e` argument, with all but the last ending with a backslash:  `sed -e '1a\' -e 'line1\' -e 'line2-and-final'` —— if you're using BSD (Mac OS X) `sed`, even that doesn't work.  You can always put the `sed` script into a file and then use `sed -f sed.script files*` to edit the files with the script.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to replace foo with bar inside a range and print some text at the end of the range? With awk you CAN write that using ranges like you HAVE to in sed:

```
awk '
/RANGE_start/,/RANGE_end/ {
    sub(/foo/,"bar")
    print
    if (/RANGE_end/) {
        print "--- This is the end of the range block ---"
    }
}
'
```

but awk also lets you use variables instead so you aren't stuck dealing with the duplicate conditions required when using ranges (note RANGE_end is only tested for once in the below script):

```
awk '
/RANGE_start/ { inRange = 1 }
inRange {
    sub(/foo/,"bar")
    print
    if (/RANGE_end/) {
        print "--- This is the end of the range block ---"
        inRange = 0
    }
}
'
```

Given that idea of handling ranges by using a flag to indicate when you're in the range, look how simple it is to select printing the range start/end lines (or anything else!) by just changing where the flag is set/tested:

```
$ seq 1 10 | awk '/3/{f=1} f{print} /7/{f=0}'
3
4
5
6
7

$ seq 1 10 | awk 'f{print} /3/{f=1} /7/{f=0}'
4
5
6
7

$ seq 1 10 | awk '/3/{f=1} /7/{f=0} f{print}'
3
4
5
6

$ seq 1 10 | awk '/7/{f=0} f{print} /3/{f=1}'
4
5
6
```

sed is great for simple substitutions on individual lines but for anything else you should be using awk for clarity, simplicity, efficiency, portability, and most other desirable software attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply that gave some clues on ways to use awk.   I'm comfortable with sed so tend to have an inbuilt bias.  I guess I've thought of awk as the "heavy lifter" and so use sed mostly if I think my solution only needs light weight.   In this case, this is part of a lengthy sed script. The issue struck me that as strange in that the new-line char, used so comprehensively and thoroughly in sed to delineate records, doesn't apply to a, c & i.  It's almost like these three commands were written later by a third-party without regard to sed's history and way of doing things.

Comment: `a lengthy sed script` - words that should never be uttered ;-). I've been using sed for 35 years and awk for 25. They are both great tools for what they are each best at. You should really invest more time in using/learning awk because if you are using sed constructs other than s, g, and p (with -n) then the awk alternative will almost always be better in almost every way. It took me 10+ years of forcing sed+grep+shell+etc. to do things they shouldn't do to figure that out. Just look at how simple and consistent **and portable** the above awk scripts are compared to the sed alterantives.