# Using sed's append/change/insert without a newline

Tags: sed, text-processing

I want to replace my pattern space in SED. I can do this with `s/^.*$/hello world/;` - but can I do it using the `c` command somehow - without using line breaks in my sed script? It's not entirely clear to me whether that's possible in any way.

(Same question for the `a` and `i` commands)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sed: Using a,c or i in a one-liner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938645/sed-using-a-c-or-i-in-a-one-liner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your shell is bash, here is a convenient way to use `c` in a one-liner:

```
$ seq 3 | sed $'/2/c\\\nNew Text'
1
New Text
3
```

This looks for any line containing `2` and changes it to `New Text`.

This uses bash's `$'...'` feature to enter a newline in a string.  The newline is represented by `\n`.  The backslash that is needed after the `c` is represented by  `\\`.

The `$'...'` feature is also available in `ksh93`, `zsh`, `mksh`, and FreeBSD `sh`.

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR

You can't control `a`,`i`,`r` et. al. They print `stuff` + `\n`.

Instead, modify the pattern space using `s` and use `P` to print pattern space up until, excluding new-line to, for desired result.

### Examples

```sh
printf 'foo\nfoo' | sed -n 'P' | cat -A
```

```
foo$
foo
```

`a`/`i` won't work

```sh
printf 'foo\nfoo' | sed -n '
#print pattern-space wo. newline
P
# apppend the char F
aF
' | cat -A
```

```
foo$
F$
foo$
F$
```

I believe it works similar to `r`/`R`. It appends after the cycle and always with newline.

But you can always use `N` with `s` instead. Ie.

```sh
printf 'foo\nfoo' | sed -n -e '
# append \n + nextline wo. its \n to pattern-space
N
' -e '
# replace the 1st \n with bar (append without trailing \n)
s@\n@bar@
' -e '
# print pattern-space up until, excluding \n
P
' | cat -A
```

```
foo$
bar$
foo$
bar
```

```sh
printf 'foo\nfoo' | sed -n -e '
# expect last-line, append \n and read next-line
$! {
  N
}
' -e '
# replace \n with bar \n
s@\n@bar\n@
' -e '
# on last line ($), append bar wo. new-line
$ { 
  s@$@bar@
}
' -e '
# print pattern-space in its entirety
p
' | cat -A
```

```
foobar$
foobar
```

#### Note

- The examples use `cat -A` to show newlines in output (`$`)
- I use `@` as a delimiter for `s`. This is personal, possibly silly, preference. It can be the standard `/`,`|` or `þ` if you like.
- I've separated commands using `-e 'cmd'`, including comments, for readability.
  Equavilent one-liner for the last is `printf 'foo\nfoo' | sed -n '$!;s@\n@bar\n@;$s@$@bar@;p' | cat -A`

## ‍♂️

#### Tip

- Use a script file, preferably in an editor like vim with `sed` syntax highlighting.

```
#!/bin/sed -f

# expect last-line, append \n and read next-line
$! {
  N
}
# replace \n with bar \n
s@\n@bar\n@
# on last line ($), append bar wo. new-line
$ { 
  s@$@bar@
}
# print
p
```

To debug

- Use `l`
  print current pattern-space with escaped special characters
- Use `=`
  print current line